# Changing Scale when Auto layout Enable, position issue

Tags: ios, autolayout

Be honest, i am not a big fan of Auto layout. But based on a job request, i have to adopt auto layout, when i was trying to do simple scale change in auto layout, the position goes wrong .

here is how the image looks in storyboard

[image]

and here is how it looks when auto layout is disabled (the result i am looking for)

[image]

and here is how it looks when auto layout is enabled (the wrong position)

[image]

and here is my constraints

[image]

And my code for changing scale:

```
self.batImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3, 3);
```

I even need 10 reputation to upload image.. and 10 reputation to post more than 2 links....

can anyone help me to post those images?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Come on! Autolayout is so much fun! :)

Didn't test it but something like this should work:

1. Remove all the constraints you have
2. Add 2 constraints to horizontal center and vertical center the batImageView into the view.
3. Add the 2 constraints more, one for the original width, one for original height.

Your batImageView constraints should look like this in the storyboard:

[image: batImageView constraints]

Now, you can add the width and height as IBOutlets to your class:

```
@property IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *batImageViewWidthConstraint;
@property IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *batImageViewHeightConstraint;
```

So you are almost done, whenever you have to change the size of the imageView just set the new constraints, for example:

```
CGFloat scaleFactor = 3.0;
self.batImageViewWidthConstraint.constant = scaleFactor * self.batImageViewWidthConstraint.constant;
self.batImageViewHeightConstraint.constant = scaleFactor * self.batImageViewHeightConstraint.constant;
[self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
```